# perfect square numbers with $0$ and $1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show that there is not an integer with digits of only $0$ and $1$ that has at least two $1$ and is a complete square number.
I tried to prove it by induction, but I couldn't.

Comment: What did you try to induct on?  The number of digits or the number of 1s?

Comment: The number of digits! @Randall if we add a 1 to the number, it will be $10a+1$ and if we add 0 it will be $10a$, where a is a number with n-1 digits,but I can't prove that it is not square!

Comment: You mean the question??? I think so... @ThomasAndrews

Comment: I meant, is there a reason you think there is no such number? For example, if it is from a problem set, there is often reason to believe it is true. :)

Comment: Actually it's a question that a professor gave me and I guess she gave it from a problem set but I'm not sure! @ThomasAndrews

Comment: [Seems to be a rather hard question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22/can-n2-have-only-digits-0-and-1-other-than-n-10k)

Comment: It suffices to show only for numbers that end with 1.  (If it ends with a single zero then it is divisible by 5 but not $5^2$ so is not a perfect square.  If it ends with multiple zeros it is a perfect square if and only removing an even number of those zeros results in a perfect square.)

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, just a bunch of necessary conditions. So suposse that $N$ has only zeros and ones, is a square but not a power of $10$:

- If there exists such a number, then there exists one that ends with $1$. Indeed, if $N$ ends with zero, then it must have an even number of trailing zeros. If you remove them, the result must be a perfect square. From now, assume that $N$ ends with $1$.
- $\sqrt N$ ends with $1$ or $9$, and begins with $3$ or $1$.
- The number of ones, $k$, is congruent to $N$ modulo $9$. Then $k$ must be a square modulo $9$. That is $k\equiv 0,1,4\text{ or }7\pmod 9$.
- The penultimate digit is $0$, because $11$ is not a square modulo $100$.
- $\sqrt N\equiv \pm1\pmod{50}$ (thanks to Thomas Andrews).

I'll edit this "answer" if I find more of them.

An heuristic reasoning: the probability that a number of at most $n$ digits has only ones and zeros is $1/5^n$. And that it is a perfect square is $1/10^{n/2}$. Assuming that both events are independent, the probability that both conditions hold for the same number is $1/(5\sqrt{10})^n$, which is lesser than $1/10^n$. So... probably, the answer is no.

Comment: It actually ends in $01$. You have that $\sqrt{N}=50k\pm 1$.

Comment: And you can show that $k$ is divisible by $5$. But it gets messier from there.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The $k$ of your second comment is my $k$ or your $k$?

Comment: Sorry, my $k{}{}{}.$

Comment: Re: the heuristic, aren't there $9*10^{n-1}$ $n$-digit numbers?

Comment: @Ivoirians Thanks, I meant "*at most* $n$ digits". Fixed.

Comment: Since $10\equiv2$, $11\equiv3$, and $101\equiv5$ mod $8$, none of which are squares mod $8$, one can assume the square number $N$, if it exists, ends in $001$.